# MySQL Workbench ERROR 1064

Tags: mysql-5.5, mysql-workbench

I have a problem with my database.  I have created the model and now I want to sync it with my database on my WAMP Server (local) but it keeps giving me an error.  I searched for the cause of the error for several days.  Since I cannot find the problem,  I've decided to share it with you.

Message log:

```
Executing SQL script in server

ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
near ') NULL DEFAULT NULL , n_category VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,    
PRIMARY K' at line 3
```

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `telo2p`.`d_category` 
(
  `idd_category` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `f_sells` DOUBLE(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `n_category` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idd_category`) 
)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_general_ci

SQL script execution finished: statements: 6 succeeded, 1 failed
```

[image: http://img855.imageshack.us/img855/4855/21725619.png]

Any advice about what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `(11)` from the `DOUBLE(11)`:

```
`f_sells` DOUBLE  NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
```

Approximate numeric dataypes (Float and Double) need no parameter. There is also a non-standard syntax with 2 parameters. From the [MySQL docs, Floating-Point Types (Approximate Value)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/floating-point-types.html):

> MySQL allows a nonstandard syntax: `FLOAT(M,D)` or `REAL(M,D)` or `DOUBLE PRECISION(M,D)`. Here, “`(M,D)`” means that values can be stored with up to `M` digits in total, of which `D` digits may be after the decimal point. For example, a column defined as `FLOAT(7,4)` will look like -999.9999 when displayed. MySQL performs rounding when storing values, so if you insert 999.00009 into a `FLOAT(7,4)` column, the approximate result is `999.0001`.

Comment: ok you know what is the thing that i have thought that thing and i remove more my eer model the (11) and for some reason when i choose Database -> sync model !  and i have put there only double without (11) it put it automatically but if i remove them from the script before i execute it all goes smooth.